# SQL query to select "name" with minimum "timestamp" grouped by "group_fk"

Tags: sql

Consider a table "t1":

```
+------------------------------+
| timestamp  | name | group_fk |
+------------+------+----------+
| 1362297600 | abc  | 41       |
| 1362384000 | bcd  | 41       |
| 1362470400 | cde  | 41       |
| 1362556800 | def  | 42       |
| 1362643200 | efg  | 42       |
+------------------------------+
```

I need to select "name" with a minimum "timestamp" in each "group_fk". So the result should be: "abc" and "def".

I know the ugly (and not always right) way to do it:

```
select name
from t1
where t1.timestamp IN (
  select min(t1_inner.timestamp)
  from t1 t1_inner
  group by t1_inner.group_fk
)
```

Is there a better solution?

--
DM

Comment: "Better" in what sense, exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done many different ways including using a subquery:

```
select t1.name, t2.minval
from table1 t1
inner join
(
  select min(timestamp) MinVal,
    group_fk
  from table1
  group by group_fk
) t2
  on t1.timestamp = t2.minval
  and t1.group_fk = t2.group_fk
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/78ac1/4).

Or if your database has windowing functions, you can use `row_number()`:

```
select name, timestamp
from 
(
  select name, timestamp,
    row_number() over(partition by group_fk order by timestamp) rn
  from table1
) src
where rn = 1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/78ac1/6)